# How to set the value from on an invisible EditText?

Tags: android

How can I get the values from the keyboard when they are typed in an invisible view?

Currently I can get the values if the EditText is visible.

`final EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

But when I make it gone

`txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

I can no longer get what keyboard is typing.

How can I make the user type in an invisible EditText?

Comment: @El_Mochiq I have a USB Card Reader, and I am trying to make an Android app that will read the Employees Card and show some information about them... But I don't want to show a text box... that is why it needs to be hidden.

Comment: You could make android:inputType="Password" or make the textcolor the same color as the background, so the text isn't showing.

Comment: @Arian : You say in the question the user is typing on a keyboard but in your comment you say you're reading their data with a card reader. So which is it?

Comment: @squonk The reader, acts as an keyboard emulator... all it does is type the id number like a physical keyboard would...

Comment: @Arian : OK - so do as El_Mochiq suggests - set the `inputType` of the `EditText` to be password style, i.e., it will show asterisks. You could try `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE` but I'm not even sure if that will work. If it doesn't then it seems like you have no choice but to make it visible with password style input.

Answer (score 1):

`View.GONE` does not make a field invisible, it removes it from the layout entirely.  Try using the [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) to see exactly how this works.

What you should do is save the text value when you set the visibility, and hold onto it until you need to use it.

Comment: Is there any other way to read a keyboard values, if I don't use a textEdit box

Comment: If you streamed it in, sure.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have a USB Card Reader, and I am trying to make an Android app that will read the Employees Card and show some information about them... But I don't want to show a text box... because there is no need for the user to see it.

Comment: What do you mean by stream it in? Can you elaborate?